# Ionic Android Platform Build Failed

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, java-home

Everytime i try to build my android platform on ionic I am greeted by the error stating that my JAVA_HOME is invalid whereas it points to the correct path as seen below. I have tried removing and re-adding the platform and re-adding the paths in the environment variables but nothing seems to work. I have been trying to troubleshoot this error for days now. Please help!

Input:

```
ionic build android
```

Output:

```
[Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75;
]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\b
uild.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: C:\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit co
de 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\com\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cord
ova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if the JAVA_HOME that it's referencing exists?  Open up a command prompt and enter: `"%Java_home%/bin/java" -version` to see what you get.  If you get anything other than version information from Java, you need to verify and update your System Variable for JAVA_HOME in your Windows Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,

in my case i set `JAVA_HOME=\Java\jdk1.7.0_45` and my actual installed version was under `jdk1.7.0_75`.

So check installed version is `jdk1.7.0_75`